# Eclipse Juno CDT 'symbole could not resolved' strange behavior

Tags: eclipse, symbols, eclipse-cdt

I have just installed eclipse juno cdt on Fedora 16. I have g++ installed.

When I first created a hello world C++ project, I have problem of iostream could not be resolved.
I corrected it by modifying the include path and it worked.

Then, I have a problem of cout and endl could not be resolved. I restarted eclipse with -clean option. It worked. But I have a problem left, g++ could not be found in the PATH.

I modified the path to point to /usr/bin/g++, restarted the eclipse (always with -clean option). This time, everything seems to be ok. I compiled and ran the code, it worked. Helloworld is displayed on screen.

But when I delete the line #include  and rewrite this line, click save. Eclipse showed error: cout and endl could not be resolved.

I really don't understand what is happening to Eclipse. Does anyone have the same problem as mine and how to resolve it in a stable manner?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Incredibly, Eclipse shows errors but it can build the project normally... I really don't understand!